# ASP.NET Imagebutton Performs jQuery function after ValidationGroup Validation

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have an issue with using both ASP.NET and jQuery in my webform.

Currently I have a multi-div registration that uses the ASP.NET clientside validation but I also want it to have jQuery animation to move from step to step.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="NextButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/registration/arrowright.png" Height="50px" onmouseover="this.src='images/registration/arrowrightgreen.png'"  onmouseout="this.src='images/registration/arrowright.png'" ValidationGroup="UserInformation" OnClientClick="onNextClick()"/>
```

I also have a jQuery function that moves to the next step of the registration.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id$=pick_user_type]").hide();
    });

    function onNextClick() {
        $("[id$=registration_div]").hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
        $("[id$=pick_user_type]").show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

The issue is that jQuery will go ahead and do the animation even if the form is invalid. Is there anyway that I can communicate to jQuery otherwise? From what I have read, ASP.NET validators will cause the `Page.Validate()` method to returns false if you have an invalidated field. Am I going to have to just move to jQuery validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like I just found out an answer. This will work on the ValidationGroup "UserInformation"

```
if (Page_ClientValidate("UserInformation")) {
    $("[id$=registration_div]").hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
    $("[id$=pick_user_type]").show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the validation of a control and the update of its display, like this:

```
ValidatorValidate($('<%= myValidator.ClientID %>'));
```

Read [ASP.NET Validation in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside) for more information about the client-side API and client-side objects.

Answer (score 0):

use valid() function.

```
if($("#form_id").valid()) 
{
  $("[id$=registration_div]").hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
  $("[id$=pick_user_type]").show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
}
```